# How to include header file across pure C and CUDA C files?

Tags: c, cuda, header-files

I need to call a **CUDA C** function `foo()` (residing in *gpu.cu*) from within a **pure C** function `main()` (residing in *main.c*). My attempt at this is illustrated below:

- **main.c** (caller):

  ```
  #include "gpu.h"
  int main();
  int main() { foo(); }
  ```
- **gpu.h** (`foo()` declaration): **<--- problem here**

  ```
  extern void foo();
  ```
- **gpu.cu** (`foo()` definition):

  ```
  #include "gpu.h"
  extern "C" void foo() { ... }
  ```
- **I get the error**:

  ```
  gpu.cu(2): error: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "foo"
  gpu.h(1): here
  ```

However, without using header files the following **does** work:

- **main.c** (caller):

  ```
  void foo();
  int main();
  int main() { foo(); }
  ```
- **gpu.cu** (`foo()` declaration and definition):

  ```
  extern "C" void foo();
  extern "C" void foo() { ... }
  ```

Of course, I would prefer using a single header file across both pure C and CUDA c code, so what is the correct syntax to use in the header file (do we still need `extern "C"` even though it's a C++ thing)? Do I need a .cuh extension?

I am compiling and linking using **NVCC only** (i.e. for both pure-C and CUDA-C code).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost have this correct - the problem is in how you are using `gpu.h`. The conflict reported by the toolchain is happening because the header file included in `gpu.cu` declares that `foo()` will have C++ linkage, but then the definition has C linkage.

The basic problem is that you are trying to use `gpu.h` as both a C and C++ header. This is usually not a good idea, but it can be made to work. One approach is to decide that it is a C header file and modify the C++ code to treat it as one, so in `gpu.cu` do this:

```
extern "C" {
#include "gpu.h"
}

extern "C" void foo() { ... };
```

The other would be to modify `gpu.h` so that its behaviour is different depending on whether it is being included by a C compiler or a C++ compiler, so something like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern void foo();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

or

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" void foo();
#else
void foo();
#endif
```

would make the preprocessor emit different code depending on whether the code is being compiled in a C or C++ environment. This may, however, fail if you try and compile any of your notionally C code using a C++ compiler.

How you choose to fix this will probably depend heavily on the real structure of your code, which I am guessing is not as simple as you have described.